Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 for a node.js server and also showing failed to upload image
I created a local server for my application with the code as above ,earlier it was running alright and sending a server code of 200 but now it sending this error:listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 server.jsserver.js continued...also despite CORS allowing jpeg files as shown in code it is showing unsupported file type,what should i do to resolve this issue?
I tried tried closing all instances of my server.js on my web browser and even terminated node.exe task from the task manager ...still facing this error.
As for the unsupported file type issue i tried removing CORS supported file extensions part and even tried .jpeg .png files but in all cases it was showing unsupported file type...SInce this is my first full stack project I am unable to clear off these issues
